# Recipe Needed to Upload Data to Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

While I've been busy finishing my Google App Engine solution during the last several months, I now find Google has me painted me into a corner due to changes and differences between the local dev_server and appspot.

The scenario: My app is deployed on appspot with Federated OpenID authentication.

The problem: Google does not support data uploads while apps are configured to use OpenID. (They are aware of this [problem](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8133) and do not consider it a bug.)

Several years ago Nick Johnson posted a [remote_api and OpenID workaround](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Using-remote-api-with-OpenID-authentication) on his blog, but several people report it no longer works.

In addition, the latest (2nd) edition of Dan Sanderson's book "Programming Google App Engine" no longer contains a chapter on data uploads. There is a chapter on Backup and Restore, but I can not restore data until I back it up, and I can not back it up until the data exists!

I can not believe I'm the only one in this predicament -- it seems it should be a very common need -- I simply need to upload data while my app uses OpenID.

Keep in mind that everything about my local dev_server Python app works great (appcfg.py, upload_data, remote_api, CSV yaml configs, etc.), but this problem on appspot prevents me from releasing my app!

Does anyone have a simple, up-to-date, and documented recipe to upload thousands of records to app engine? Custom upload handler endpoint? Bundle the data file(s) with new app verions, then read them somehow? Post CSV files to Google Drive and read them from a task queue?

Any ideas?

Comment: Or upload to the blobstore and read them with a taskqueue. The blobstore is the preferred way to upload data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this as a work around:

1. Create a new application with "normal" Google account authentication.
2. Upload the data into that application.
3. Backup the data into Google Cloud Storage.
4. Restore the date from Google Cloud Storage into the original application.

Comment: Thanks, Shay. Sounds like an [intriguing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview) workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As of SDK 1.7.3 google says you can change the authentication method  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes .  You could always revert to "google accounts api" whilst doing you initial data load via remote api, then set auth back to Federated Login once your done.

Comment: I did just that to work-around the problem at-first, however it took several weeks to upload several thousand records while living within my daily quota. After I completed my initial set of uploads another new bug prevented me from switching back to OpenID -- this bug lasted for about three months, for which my app was dead in the water. If I had production users it would never be feasible to switch back to upload new data, since the process takes so long, plus I'd hate to risk another 3 month outage! But thanks for the suggestion!